# How to make NFS accesses time out much faster

Tags: nfs, mount

We have a load-balanced web app that serves some images off an NFS mounted drive.

When the NFS server goes down, it ends up bringing all of the web instances down.

Currently the volume is mounted with:

```
ip:/path/to/images /docroot/images nfs soft,intr,rw,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 0 0
```

I ran a siege test against a selection of images that live on this volume, and when it went down requests ended up timing out based on the apache Timeout value (which was set to 600 sec for this test).

I changed the mount options to:

```
bg,soft,intr,rw,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=5,retrans=2,actimeo=60,retry=15
```

And this was better, but still took too long to fail:  The first set of request timed out in about 30 seconds, but the next set took anywhere from 180 to 300s.

I know the long-term solution is to move these to S3, but is it possible to reduce this to under 5-10s without affecting performance?

Comment: Why are you serving the files directly from a shared NFS server in the first place? It sounds like a single point of failure that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @kasperd: it is a single point of failure, and we are planning on moving image storage to S3, but we inherited this architecture and are trying to reduce the potential impact of a failure.

Answer (score 3):

Soft rw mounts can "cause silent data corruption in certain cases." Consider using a ro mount. Assuming Linux is the OS, the [NFS man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs) lists the mount options you can change. Without testing, given a TCP soft mount (read only) `timeo=1` and `retrans=3` would cause the operation to fail in 6 seconds. ("The NFS client performs linear backoff: After each retransmission the timeout is increased by `timeo`...")

Comment: According to the documentation, the timeo value is in 10th of seconds, and only applies if the soft option is enabled.  So the settings I have should fail in under 3s, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I did some testing with Ubuntu Precise with "mount -o nfsvers=3,soft,timeo=10,retrans=3,ro server:/srv/homes  /srv/homes". I then stopped the NFS server. After the first timeout I got consistent 6s timeouts: (1) `time cat System.map-3.2.0-31-generic > /dev/null`: real 0m16.033 (2) `time cat System.map-3.2.0-29-generic > /dev/null`: real 0m6.011s, (3) `time cat initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic > /dev/null` real 0m6.011s